# Infinite loop on coin convertion

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, infinite

This program is supposed to be a coin converter which converts dollar values to yen, and then yen values to dollar. On the yen conversion its supposed to stop once there are no more input values. I'm not being able to get out of the loop. Tried several options, none worked.

```
int main()
{
    double exchangeRate,
        yen = 0,
        us = -1;
    bool pass = true;

    cout << "Introduce current US-Yen exchange rate: ";
    cin >> exchangeRate;

    cout << "US dollar value (0 for break): ";

    while (pass)
    {
        cin >> us;
        if (us == 0)
            pass = false;
        else
        {
            yen = us * exchangeRate;
            cout << "Yen: " << yen << "\n";

        }
    }

    bool pass2 = true;
    exchangeRate = 1 / exchangeRate;

    cout << "Yen values: ";

    while (pass2)
    {
        cin >> yen;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            pass2 = false;
            cout << "123 \n";
        }
        else
        {
            us = yen * exchangeRate;
            cout << "US: " << us << "\n";
        }
    }

    cout << "Thank you! \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Also tried to stick the `cin >> yen` inside the `else` statement. Same problem, still looping.

Comment: How about posting a more complete example?  Things like data types of `yen` matter.

Comment: How is the program supposed to know when there are no more input values? Depending on the shell you can signal EOF on `cin` using a keyboard command, but one of these homework assignments usually asks for a sentinel value. What method do you WANT to use?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for `std::basic_istream` (the common base for all types that represent input streams) more carefully.   Encountering end of file in a stream does not set the fail bit, so `cin.fail()` will not detect it.    It is quite feasible for `cin.fail()` to return `false` when `cin.eof()` returns `true`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/w3uePA

Comment: What are you expecting should happen? What do you believe will cause `cin.fail()` to be true? (That's supposed to be taken as an invitation to explain why you wrote the code the way you did, not a criticism.)

Comment: Was expecting that, by the time the buffer was empty, the if statement would turn false, thus shifting the pass2 boolean and finishing the loop. The first half of the exercise asked for a sentinel value, but the second half is the one causing trouble. Sorry for the noob question, fist time posting. Thank you very much for your fast answers! Cheers!

Comment: @barberchopz You did however not get a proper answer. If we'd been able to reproduce the problem using your code we would perhaps be able to answer it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @barberchopz *"by the time the buffer was empty"* -- this seems like a strange thing to consider, given that the computer processes input so much faster than a human can type. In one respect, the buffer for `cin` is empty most of the time as the program tends to be waiting for the next keystroke more often than the buffer is waiting for the program to catch up. From another perspective, since there could be a next keystroke, `cin` is never really empty.